# reference an image in rails from style tag

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

How can I reference an image in rails erb file which is in inside the style tag?

```
 <div class="item" style="background-image: url(images/slider/bg2.jpg)">
```

The above url will work in the html version when not using rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
<div class="item" style="background-image: url(<%= asset_path('bg2.jpg') %>)">
```